# Reactjs Concat with prev state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple react code

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      textarea: 'Hello World! \n \nTry to press Shift enter after Hello \n \nShould be like this \nHello \nWorld! '
    };
  }
  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ textarea: e.target.value })
  }
  handlePress = e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState(prevState => ({ textarea: prevState.textarea.concat('\n why here') }))
    } else if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();

    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <textarea style={{ height: 200, width: 200 }} value={this.state.textarea} onKeyDown={this.handlePress} onChange={this.onChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('code'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='code'></div>
```

[image]

**Should Be like this**

[image]

Can anyone help me please or just guide me to correct way I'm stack in this problem even I don't know how to explain it to make a research

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this fragment of your code:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ textarea: prevState.textarea.concat('\n why here') }))
```

you concat the previous textarea state with some string - in your case `"\n why here"`. It joins the end of the former string with the beginning of the latter - nothing more, nothing less.

As you see, there is no notion of a cursor in your code - you don't specify correctly where `"\n why here"` should be put.

Please have a look at `selectionStart` (and maybe `selectionEnd`) to get cursor's position.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/selectionStart

Then, change the concat part of your logic to insert your string in desired position.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `selectionStart` value to get cursor position and break the text at that position and use `.slice` method to set the value back to state after appending `\n`;

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      textarea: 'Hello World! \n \nTry to press Shift enter after Hello \n \nShould be like this \nHello \nWorld! '
    };
  }
  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ textarea: e.target.value })
  }
  handlePress = e => {
    e.persist();
    if (e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const pos = e.target.selectionStart;
      console.log(this.state.textarea)
      this.setState(prevState => ({ textarea: prevState.textarea.slice(0, pos) + " \n " + prevState.textarea.slice(pos) }))
    } else if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();

    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <textarea style={{ height: 200, width: 200 }} value={this.state.textarea} onKeyDown={this.handlePress} onChange={this.onChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('code'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='code'></div>
```